# How would I get an object from the value of one of its fields?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a few tree objects, I want to create a method (or use one that already exists) that works similarly to this:

`GetObjectGivenField(FieldNameGoesHere, FieldValueGoesHere)` and it would return the object that is specific to that field.

The code I currently have:

```
using System;

namespace Forest
{
    class Tree
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Height;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tree fir = new Tree()
            {
                Name = "Fir",
                Height = 100
            };
            Tree oak = new Tree()
            {
                Name = "Oak",
                Height = 80
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Give me the name of a tree, I'll return it's height.");
            string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("A {0}! The height of that is {1}!", UserInput, OBJECT_NAME_HERE.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you plan to store the trees?

Comment: Consider creating a `List<Tree>` and add your trees to it. Then you can use LINQ methods to easily find the `Tree` that matches the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
void Main()
{
        var trees = new List<Tree>();
        trees.Add(new Tree()
        {
            Name = "Fir",
            Height = 100
        });
        trees.Add(new Tree()
        {
            Name = "Oak",
            Height = 80
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Give me the name of a tree, I'll return it's height.");
        string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("A {0}! The height of that is {1}!", UserInput, trees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == UserInput).Height );
}
class Tree
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Height  {get;set;}


}
```

Mind you, this solution will only work if the user enters a tree name that exists. FirstOrDefault returns null in case the entered name does not exist and Console.WriteLine will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As Heretic Monkey said in the comments, use [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) where T is your object's type. Then you can use the `Single` extension method from the [`System.Linq.Enumerable` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var trees = new List<Tree> { fir, oak };
var tree = trees.Single(t => t.Name == UserInput);
Console.WriteLine("A {0}! The height of that is {1}!", UserInput, tree.Height);
```

You will have to add the following using statements at the top of the file in order to use this code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Note that `Single` will throw an exception if there is not exactly one `Tree` with the given name. I chose this method because it most similarly resembled what your question asked, but if you want more comprehensive error handling, you can use `SingleOrDefault` instead:

```
var trees = new List<Tree> { fir, oak };
var tree = trees.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == UserInput);
if (tree == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I don't recognize that tree name.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("A {0}! The height of that is {1}!", UserInput, tree.Height);
}
```

Comment: From your link (`Single`): "Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence." Houston, we have a problem!

Comment: Am I expected to predict what error handling functionality he wants? But I'll edit the answer to note it.

Comment: I wouldn't say you need to predict the specifics of how they want to handle the errors but I do think it's best to not blindly dot into a possible null reference. Making a note of it is good enough for me. +1